# DisplayTag library question - Is it possible to add more info to the standard Excel export?

Tags: displaytag

I'm using the DisplayTag library (http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/) for tables in my JSP and I'm taking advantage of the export functionality that comes with it.

I want to export the table contents to an Excel file but I want to modify what is written out to the Excel file to include extra information and to change the format of the data.

Is it possible to specify a decorator to get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is discussed in the documentation [here](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_decorators.html#Table_decorators_and_exports). To use their example:

```
<display:table name="test" export="true">
    <display:setProperty name="decorator.media.html"  value="org.displaytag.sample.decorators.HtmlTotalWrapper" />
    <display:setProperty name="decorator.media.excel" value="org.displaytag.sample.decorators.HssfTotalWrapper" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

> media="html"

In order to separate what you will display in html and what in Excel. Moreover you might have a class named ExcelView and define what you want to print in the exported file. Something like [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/displaytag/displaytag/1.2/org/displaytag/export/ExcelView.java#ExcelView)